# Calculating database size percentage used in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently running `db.stats` on a database and then I get back some information that includes `dataSize` and `storageSize`.

Now I'd imagine that

- `dataSize` is how much data is in the database
- `storageSize` is how much data I could store before the database is full.

BUT when I do a calculation like `(dataSize/totalSize) * 100` to find the percentage of space that's used in the db, I get a number that's almost always greater than 100%.

How can I use `db.stats` to tell me how much of the database space I'm currently using?

I'm using Mongo 3.6 atm.

Comment: WiredTiger compresses data files, so storageSize can be lower than dataSize (and storage also includes indexSize)

Answer (score 7):

Briefly:

- `dataSize`: The total size of the uncompressed data held in this database.
- `storageSize`: The total amount of space allocated to collections in this database for document storage. This is the size (in bytes) of all the data extents in the database and it includes allocated-but-unused space in the data extents and space vacated by deleted documents within the data extents.

More details in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/).

However, neither of these metrics tell you anything about the maximum *available* space for a MongoDB database because storage footprint in MongoDB is not capped *per database*. Instead, you might want to think about how much diskspace you have made available to your MongoDB instance and then assess how much of that is in use by your database. Mongo v3.6 added two new dbstats metrics which are useful here:

> **dbStats.fsUsedSize**
>
> Total size of all disk space in use on the filesystem where MongoDB stores data.
>
> **dbStats.fsTotalSize**
>
> Total size of all disk capacity on the filesystem where MongoDB stores data.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using `db.stats(1024)` or `db.runCommand({ dbStats: 1, scale: 1024 }) -- 1024` to convert the size in KB is only  available in Mongo v 3.6. It can give you total disc space allocated and how much of it is used:

```
dbStats.fsUsedSize
```

Total size of the disk space in use on the filesystem where MongoDB stores the data.

```
dbStats.fsTotalSize
```

Total size of the disk capacity on the filesystem where MongoDB stores the data.

You can also cross-check it with filesystem command (only for Linux if you have access) and provided you know the partition path where the data is stored, which can be found in `mongod.cfg`

```
$ df -h

Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/vg--data-data         **70G  9.1G   61G**  13% /data
```